# What happens if you run out of CQ points to pay test fees?

Tags: splatoon-2, splatoon-2-octo-expansion

In Splatoon 2 Octo Expansion, it so far costs at least 100 CQ points to enter a level with 3 lives. You gain some throughout the level, and get a bonus at the end, but what happens if you completely run out? Is there any way to farm enough to get back into the game? Or is this a game over?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pearl takes some Money from her Dad. Marina transforms it into CQ points. You get 3000 Ponts and you can continue. But you have to pay it back later.

Comment: If you continue to run out of CQ Points, can you continuously borrow money and rack up a huge debt?