# How do I get Pearl to take money from her dad?

Tags: splatoon-2, splatoon-2-octo-expansion

I have run out of CQ points on the octo expansion. I can't figure out how to get Pearl to take money from her dad so I can get more points. What am I missing?

Comment: According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/8qzxbu/when_you_run_out_of_points_in_the_octo_expansion/), it sounds like it'll happen when you try paying the test fee for a level without having enough CQ Points. Have you tried starting a level without any money yet?

Comment: Related: [*What happens if you run out of CQ points to pay test fees?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/333751/181240)

Answer (score 1):

**Pearl will lend you 3,000 CQ Points if you fail a level while you have less than 100 CQ points.**

Most stages have an entry fee more expensive than 100 points, so it's possible to not have enough points for a specific stage without getting a loan from Pearl. If this happens, you will need to replay an earlier stage with a less expensive fee.