# Is it possible to go below 100 CQ Points?

Tags: splatoon-2, splatoon-2-octo-expansion

Each level in the campaign requires some amount of CQ Points, with the lowest being 100. If you don't have enough points to play a level, you'll have to go to cheaper levels and grind them before you can play the more expensive one. If you fall below 100 points, Pearl will "borrow" some money from her dad and Marina will transfer it into 3,000 CQ Points.

After beating the campaign, you're able to use a vending machine that dispenses items for the main game for 15,000 CQ Points apiece. Is it possible to use the vending machine when you have 15,000-15,099 points? And if so, does Pearl steal from her dad's wallet to give you more points?

Comment: Related: [*What happens if you run out of CQ points to pay test fees?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/333751/181240)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can. When you spend the CQ Points to get an item, nothing happens until you get back on the train. On the train, the whole "you ran out of points" sequence starts and you're loaned 3,000 points.